# Why hasNextInt() returning false over here?

Tags: java, arrays, file

I have file MatrixToCsv.csv like this:

---

```
67,85,20,87,78,46,66;
33,66,88,24,90,28,19;
76,22,46,33,10,16,73;
16,79,28,98,67,49,62;
85,75,12,18,92,58,80;
59,89,16,10,52,67,35;
54,66,62,53,39,91,37;
```

---

And i want to save it to an array but only the integers, so I have written this:

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Scanner input = new Scanner (new File("MatrixToCsv.csv"));
    int rows = 7;
    int columns = 7;
    int[][] array = new int[rows][columns];

    input.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile(",|;|(\\n)"));
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < columns; ++j)
        {
            if(input.hasNextInt())
            {
                array[i][j] = input.nextInt();
            }  
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            System.out.print(array[i][j]+ " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    input.close();
}
```

And the output is:

---

```
 67 85 20 87 78 46 66 
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

---

And I am wondering why it reads only one line from text. Thanks. Q.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
input.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile(",|;|(\\n)"));
```

Here, you are basically saying that the delimiter can be a *single* comma *OR* a *single* semicolon *OR* a *single* newline character.

At the end of each line you have both semicolon and newline, which is not what you set your scanner to use as delimiter. Use `[,;\\n]+` instead, which means "one between `,`, `;` and `\n` repeated at least one time". This way you'll match `;\n` too.

```
input.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("[,;\\n]+"));
```

[See it in action](https://ideone.com/kQQOOy)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Have a great day! Q.